# a long string including r\n\ repeatedly to be manipulated in a for loop in python 3.5

Tags: python, string

i am trying to set a for loop in a string for webservice query but the string has lots of r\n\ s inside where i can not set the correct positioning.

i have tried several ways to solve it but none of them placed correctly, that is an easy one for my former experience but that r\n\ things are making it extremely hard to read and manipulate

```
string = "{\r\n\"header\": [{\r\n\"key\": \"transactionId\",\r\n\"value\": \"317ec740-95fa-4345-bf25-2df733afd322\"\r\n}, {\r\n\"key\": \"application\",\r\n\"value\": \"UYGULAMA_ADI\"\r\n}],\r\n\"body\": {\r\n\"deliveryDay\": \"2019-07-10T00:00:00.000+0300\",\r\n\"region\": \"TR1\"\r\n}\r\n}"
```

i am trying to convert the date "2019-07-10" format from string to variable where i can ask for different days in just one for loop.

Comment: `data = json.loads(string)`, `print( data['body']['deliveryDay'] )`

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem is, but given that you mention `r\n\ ` a couple of times perhaps you're confused about what the backslashes (`\ `) do. The `\r\n` is a new-line, carriage return (the standard way of indicating a new line should start in DOS/Windows). Note the backslash comes **before** the letter. Then, the `\"` means a literal double quote, as apposed to the double quote right at the end of the string that terminates the string.

Answer (score 1):

That's JSON. You should parse it into objects, then work with those, then generate new JSON when you're done.

If you have good reasons to process a structured format like JSON as a string... why don't you just remove all `\r\n` from it? The result will still be valid JSON. And it doesn't look like any of the fields contains line breaks inside string values.